# which sqlfluff command not showing executable path

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use the sqlfluff extension (extentsion id dorzey.vscode-sqlfluff) in vs code. When I save a sql file I get the following error message in vs code:

"Cannot lint /home/usr/file.sql. The executable was not found. Use the 'Executable Path' setting to configure the location of the executable."

I followed the extensions configuration doecumentation which states:

"The extension expects sqlfluff to be installed and already added to the path. If it is installed but cannot be found, add the path to your preferences as seen below. Find the path by typing which sqlfluff into your terminal."

However, `which sqlfluff` doesn't print the path in the terminal. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

To specify a custom path to sqlfluff in VS Code,

1. Open a command prompt and run `python -c "import shutil; print(shutil.which('sqlfluff'))"` This will print out the path to your local sqlfluff installation.
2. Copy the path that is printed out. It should end in *"sqlfluff.EXE"*
3. In VS Code, click File --> Preferences --> Settings
4. Find the setting for *"Sqlfluff: Executable Path"*. Paste the path there.

Answer (score 2):

`vscode-sqlfluff` does not install `sqlfluff` itself. You have to install it by yourself.

Follow [sqlfluff installation guide](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/gettingstarted.html#installing-sqlfluff)

Answer (score 1):

In the most recent version of the extension, there are three parts that need to be properly configured:

1. Executable Path on OS (Windows in my case):

- Install Python and Pip, then install sqlfluff using pip:

  `$ pip install sqlfluff`
- Verify the package installation by checking the sqlfluff version:

  `sqlfluff version`

and you should get a response similar to:

```
2.3.2
```

- Check executable location:

  `where sqlfluff`
- Add the sqlfluff directory to your path:

  This PC > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Environment Variables > System Variables > Path > New > [Insert executable directory here]

2. Executable Path on VS Code:

- Assuming the extension is already installed, navigate to File > Preferences > Settings
- Search for `sqlfluff`
- Modify the `Sqlfluff: Executable Path` setting to point to the sqlfluff executable exposed by `where sqlfluff` above. e.g.

[image: Sqlfluff: Executable Path]

3. Sqlfluff working directory in **User** and **Workspace** on VSCode Settings

Provide the directory in which the executable is found for **both**.

[image: Sqlfluff working directory]

Sqlfluff should now run properly.